# How do I clean install windows 7 on the "other" partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, windows-7

I would like to cleanly install windows 7 on another partition to ubuntu 12.04.

I originally had a windows 7 only machine. I subsequently installed ubuntu 12.04 alongside it by creating a partition.

Windows 7 now seems to be corrupted - when it starts loading it eventually shows a blue screen with what looks like a memory related error message. The boot loader (if that is the right terminology) appears to be working as I can get into ubuntu fine, and windows does start to load.

I am confused about what hard drives and partitions I actually have, and where each OS is. I am not even sure if I have one or two physical hard drives. Here are screenshots of my drives / partitions.

[image]
[image]

I have a windows 7 CD (came with my PC).

What do I need to do to get windows 7 working again?

FYI: I am not experienced with partitioning, nor massively experienced with windows nor linux. However, I do have a few years of coding experience.

Comment: Possible duplicate. Refer this > [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/6321/179042)

Answer (score 0):

Would you go to this site and follow the instructions on how to get the boot-info URL to post?
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

I will be able to look at everything I will probably need to see to help you troubleshoot this better.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Here's the general outline:

```
1.Make space for Windows 7
2.Install Windows 7
3.Reinstate GRUB
4.Mount the /boot partition
5.Install the boot loader
```

Step One

Open up GParted, and make sure that you have at least 20 GB available for Windows 7, either as a partition you can remove, or as unpartitioned space. If it's a partition, remove it from GRUB to make sure it doesn't break your Ubuntu install -- GParted will complain if anything bad is about to happen. Make note of current /boot device. If that doesn't show up there, make note of the / device. The device name is something like sda5.

Step Two

Install Windows 7 into the space you just made

Step Three

Load up from your Ubuntu live CD, and then run these commands.

If you DO NOT have a separate /boot partition:

```
sudo mount /dev/DEVICENAME_FROM_STEP_ONE /mnt
sudo rm -rf /boot    # Careful here, make sure YOU ARE USING THE LIVE CD. I tried,
it works.
sudo ln -s /mnt/boot /boot
```

If you have a SEPARATE /boot partition:

```
sudo mount /dev/DEVICENAME_FROM_STEP_ONE /boot
```

Step Four

Then continue with those commands:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install grub-pc
sudo grub-install /dev/sda     # NOTE THAT THERE IS NO DIGIT
sudo umount /boot
```

And restart. It should work fine and boot both systems.